# Can't iterate big amount of html with foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have a work in peogress project. I need code to edit docx files' metadata. Now I can unzip docx files and show/edit the relevant metadata in forms. It works like this:
[image]

Now I am also able to upload multiple files, unzip and so on. However I am not able to iterate the form (which is shown on the image above) with foreach. This is the code I want to iterate:

```
 <h2><?php echo "$target" ?></h2>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">

        <h3>Tulajdonságok</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
                  <form role="form" action="rewrite.php" method="get">
<?php 
    foreach ($tomb2[1] as $key => $metaname){
        $talalat = $tomb[1][$key]; 
        echo '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="tulajdonsag[]" value="' . "$metaname\n"  . '">' . '<br>';
    }
?>
 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
         <h3>Tulajdonságok értékei</h3>
          <div class="form-group">

<?php 
    foreach ($tomb2[1] as $key => $metaname){
        $talalat = $tomb[1][$key]; 
        echo '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="metavalue[]" value="' . "$talalat\n" . '">' . '<br>';
    }
?>
             </div>
```

The code is also on Gitlab : https://gitlab.com/rokayattila/metaadat/tree/358126fa55bff53378d3044b1a40ce9626e6f06b (upload.php and values.html are the relevant files).

Comment: What do you mean `I am not able to iterate the form  with foreach`? Errors or something? Also consider using single `foreach` to gather information instead of re-looping your data for each field.

Comment: setting $talalat just to echo it is unnecessary allocation, in the first foreach you dont even use it..

Comment: " Errors or something? " there are no errors. The metadata of the last uploaded file appears in the form (you can see on the image). I need the metadata of all the files, nut just the last one.